# RxJava from list with async wait for callback

Tags: java, rx-java, observable, rx-java2

```
List<String> listExample = Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three");
```

Think of i have list of string, and using **RxJava ([Observable.fromArray](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/from.html))**

```
Observable.fromArray(ids.toArray(new String[ids.size()])).subscribe(new Consumer<String>() {
    @Override
    public void accept(@NonNull String s) throws Exception {

    }
});
```

Here think each string has a Async callback here once i receive that callback it should move to next string. Is it possible using rxjava?

This is the code which i'am having currently, it doesn't wait for till the callback right!.

```
for (String id : ids) {
    getMessage(id, new urlGenCallback() {
        @Override
        public void urlAndToken(String url, String token, String idx) {

        }
    });
}
```

Thank you **@Geoffrey Marizy**

Answer: [Check Below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44414282/3257284)
For More Info About ConcatMap [Visit Here](https://medium.com/appunite-edu-collection/rxjava-flatmap-switchmap-and-concatmap-differences-examples-6d1f3ff88ee0)

Comment: Put you answer as an answer, not an edit of your question. Or improve the question which helped you get there.

Comment: Since the issue is solved, th stack-overflow way of doing things is to mark the answer which solved it as "accepted"

Answer (score 1):

You are looking to the [concatMap](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#concatMap(io.reactivex.functions.Function)) operator. A complete article on this topic: https://fernandocejas.com/2015/01/11/rxjava-observable-tranformation-concatmap-vs-flatmap/

Wrap your request as an Observable, then pass it as a parameter to concatMap :

```
Observable.fromArray(ids.toArray(new String[ids.size()])).concatMap(/* your request returning an Observable */)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Observable.fromArray(ids.toArray(new String[ids.size()]))
        .concatMap(s -> {
            return Observable.create(new ObservableOnSubscribe<String>() {
                @Override
                public void subscribe(@NonNull ObservableEmitter<String> e) throws Exception {
                    getMessage(s, new urlGenCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void urlAndToken(String url, String token, String id) {
                            e.onNext("......");
                            e.onComplete();
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }).subscribe(new Consumer<String>() {
    @Override
    public void accept(@NonNull String s) throws Exception {
       //All other code goes here
    }
});
```